# how to find the css style attribute of a particular html element using Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation, robotframework

I am writing an automation test script using Robot Framework & Selenium2Library for testing our web application( in `.txt` format) . One of my test cases involves to check the CSS style attribute of an HTML tag.

Is there any specific keyword in Robot Framework to obtain the CSS style attribute of an html element?

Here is my testing scenario:

```
<div id="check_style" style="width:20px;height:20px;background-color:#ffcc00;"></div>
```

Now, I have to store the background color of this particular html tag into a variable `${bg_color}`. Is there any specific keyword in Robot Framework to do this process?

Can you please suggest an effective way to handle this situation?

> I think we can make use of this javascript function for the above mentioned purpose :
>
> `document.getElementById("check_style").style["background-color"]`
>
> But how to make use of this particular function to store the value of background-color inot a variable `${bg_color}`  ?
>
> ( I have tried to execute `${bg_color} =  Execute Javascript  document.getElementById("check_style").style["background-color"]`,
>   but didn't work ! )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Selenium2Library [Get Element Attribute](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute) keyword to get the style attribute:

```
| | ${style}= | Get element attribute | id=check_style@style
```

You can then either use a regular expression to find the background color attribute or do some additional parsing. The latter would be easier to do in python than with robot keywords.

For example, if you understand regular expressions, something like the following might work. Of course, you'll probably want to add some bullet-proofing.

```
| | ${style}= | get element attribute | id=check_style@style
| | ${color}= | evaluate | re.search("background-color: *(.*?);", '''${style}''').group(1) | re
```

Note: you might not get the same literal value as is in the raw HTML. For example, on my machine `${color}` comes back as `rgb(255, 204, 0)` even though the color in the HTML is `#ffcc00`.

Comment: I have tried with `Get Element Attribute`  keyword .. But it's returning a value  **.None**  ! Also, how to abstract a particular css attribute only using this keyword (eg. background-color)? [ Am not using python, am writing test cases in `.txt` format ] . Can we do some thing like this  for obtaining a specific attribute  `Get Element Attribute  id=check_style@background-color` ?

Comment: @ArunRamachandran: no, you cannot use `Get Element Attribute` to get `background-color`; `background-color` isn't an element attribute. You can use it to get the style, like I showed in my example, and  you can then parse the result to get the background color, also as I showed in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the solution ! But , can we directly make use of regular expressions in robot framework ( if am writing test cases in `.txt` format ) ? i.e Can we make use of regular expressions in test cases even if we are not writing test cases in python ?

Comment: @ArunRamachandran: my example shows how to use regular expressions in robot test cases. The example is written in the text format, except it is using pipes instead of spaces for clarity. The same solution will work in all formats.

Comment: Sorry ... I got an error while executing the code !  **Failed: NameError: name 're' is not defined*** !    Here is the full error description:  **Evaluating expression   're.search("background-color: * (.?*);", '''width:20px;height:20px;background-color:#ffcc00;''').group(1)'   failed: NameError:  name 're' is not defined**                                                  Am I missing something ? Do I have to include any other library ?

Comment: @ArunRamachandran: my apologies. I accidentally left off a tiny piece of code. I've updated my answer to include "| re" at the end of the second line.

Comment: Thanks alot ! It's working right now :) ... How did it happen ?

Comment: Note that this will fail if style is for example: "margin-left: 2px; left: 5px;'", searching for "left" will return 2px instead of 5px. You need to exclude starting with "-" by adding "[^-]" at the beginning of the regex, so the full regex should be "[^-]style-name: *(.*?);"

Comment: Also, in order to work when looking for the first style, you'll need to add a space to account not starting with "-".  Here's my full line of code in Python:   value = re.search('[^-]{}: *(.*?);'.format(style_name), ' ' + style).

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason I had a bunch of trouble getting this to work. I think it's because my CSS was defined in an external file (therefore pulling the `style` attribute came up empty).

Also note that RF now has changed the definition of Get Element Attribute to take two parameters, not one.

I'd like to pass along a great solution I found after a bunch of searching -- I found this amazing keyword here [How to get the css style of text-overflow in robot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001999/how-to-get-the-css-style-of-text-overflow-in-robot-framework)

```
*** Keywords ***
Get CSS Property Value
    [Documentation]
    ...    Get the CSS property value of an Element.
    ...    
    ...    This keyword retrieves the CSS property value of an element. The element
    ...    is retrieved using the locator.
    ...    
    ...    Arguments:
    ...    - locator           (string)    any Selenium Library supported locator xpath/css/id etc.
    ...    - property_name     (string)    the name of the css property for which the value is returned.
    ...    
    ...    Returns             (string)    returns the string value of the given css attribute or fails.
    ...        
    [Arguments]    ${locator}    ${attribute name}
    ${css}=         Get WebElement    ${locator}
    ${prop_val}=    Call Method       ${css}    value_of_css_property    ${attribute name}
    [Return]     ${prop_val}
```

after which I could simply run

```
    ${style}=    Get CSS Property Value    class:logo    background-image
```

and do a plain text comparison. Sub in any CSS value for background-image and have fun with this!

Answer (score 0):

Get css value using javascript in robot framework. [link here](https://adiralashivaprasad.blogspot.in/2018/05/how-to-get-css-attribute-value-in-robot.html)

```
# Get element using Xpath in JavaScript.
${element}=    Set Variable    document.evaluate("${xpath_locator}", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue

# Get css attribute value using getComputedStyle()
${attribute_value}=    Execute Javascript    return window.getComputedStyle(${element},null).getPropertyValue('${css_attribute}');

Log   ${attribute_value}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19775417)

Comment: Updated, Can you review and let me Know, if it didn't work