# How to get the css style of text-overflow in robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

How to get the css style of **text-overflow** in robot framework. For validating the ellipsis text.

```
<td _ngcontent-c5="" class="fontStyle" data-placement="top" title="123456789123456789qwertyuiasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjkqwertyuiasdfghjkzxcvbnmertyui"> 123456789123456789qwertyuiasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjkqwertyuiasdfghjkzxcvbnmertyui </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: in the current SeleniumLibrary (3.2+) there is a dedicated keyword: [Get Element Attribute](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute)

---

Getting a value of a CSS property is not supported in the SeleniumLibrary for Robot Framework. However, there is a method called `value_of_css_property` in the Selenium Python module that does exactly that.

In order to call a method on an element the standard keyword `Call Method` can be used on any Robot variable or object. In the below example I created a custom keyword and some examples using the Google main page. They should be easily modified for your purpose.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers

*** Test Cases ***
TC
    Open Browser    http://www.google.com    Chrome

    # a CSS property from the element.
    ${element_prop}=    Get CSS Property Value    id=SIvCob    line-height
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${element_prop}    28px

    # a CSS property inherited from the <body> tag.
    ${body_prop}=    Get CSS Property Value    id=SIvCob    font-family
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${body_prop}    arial, sans-serif

*** Keywords ***
Get CSS Property Value
    [Documentation]
    ...    Get the CSS property value of an Element.
    ...    
    ...    This keyword retrieves the CSS property value of an element. The element
    ...    is retrieved using the locator.
    ...    
    ...    Arguments:
    ...    - locator           (string)    any Selenium Library supported locator xpath/css/id etc.
    ...    - property_name     (string)    the name of the css property for which the value is returned.
    ...    
    ...    Returns             (string)    returns the string value of the given css attribute or fails.
    ...        
    [Arguments]    ${locator}    ${attribute name}
    ${css}=         Get WebElement    ${locator}
    ${prop_val}=    Call Method       ${css}    value_of_css_property    ${attribute name}
    [Return]     ${prop_val}
```

Comment: Hi @A. kootstra     To validate text styling like font size/bold/italic/text color what are the keywords/library one should look at in robot framework?

Comment: These can either be attributes of your element, or more likely, CSS properties. If they are the latter, then this keyword can be used to check for their particular value. Have a look at your Browsers Developer tools to check those. If you want to know more, please create a new question as this really shouldn't be discussed here.

Comment: Please create a new question for this. It goes beyond the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

in robot framework to get text you can use,
this will store text in variable `data`

```
${data}    Get Text    xpath=*//td[@class='fontStyle' and @data-placement='top']
```

this will give you `data` variable as `123456789123456789qwertyuiasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjkqwertyuiasdfghjkzxcvbnmertyui`

for validation you can use

for partial match use :

```
Element Should Contain    locator    text_should_check_with
```

for exact match use :

```
Element Text Should Be    locator    text_should_check_with
```

Comment: I need to check the displayed text are ellipsis. By getting the css style of text-overflow: ellipsis